# Pass GET and read mySQL using GET

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am currently stuck on a bug where I need to pass a parameter value from the url to a `PHP`file on the back-end.

What the URL looks like `?p=tasks&t=view_task&id=1`. I need to pass the `id`with the value `1`to my page which is located at i.e `url: '/core/views/task_comments.php'`.

```
var seconds = 1000; // time in milliseconds
var tc_reload = function() {
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/core/views/task_comments.php',
     data: {id: id},
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {
       $('#task-comments').html(data);
       setTimeout(function() {
         tc_reload();
       }, seconds);
     }
   });
 };
 tc_reload();
```

And on the PHP page I got the following code.

```
// Fetch task data
$task_fetch = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM system_tasks WHERE task_id = :task_id");
$task_fetch->bindValue(":task_id", $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$task_fetch->execute();
```

What I receive is the following error.

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\views\task_comments.php on line 19`

I would love to know what went **wrong**.

Comment: Where you define `id` in your code???

Comment: It should be `id` instead of `task_id`. Updated the code @Saty

Comment: @Samuel is the value from javascript of the id set ?

Comment: `id` is defined in the url, `?p=tasks&t=view_task&id=1`. Shouldn't I be able to send the `GET` parameter value to the `PHP` page? @Cosmin

Comment: You're not sending the `p` and `t` parameters in your AJAX call.

Comment: @Samuel We mean where are you setting the variable `id` used in `data: { id: id }`?

Comment: @Samuel In the javascript I ask. Make an `alert(id);` and see if it is set

Comment: @Cosmin It's not set.

Comment: @Barmar I just need to send the `id`.

Comment: @Samuel then that is your problem... fix it

Comment: @Cosmin I set the id to the parameter value, `var id = $.urlParam('id');`.

Comment: Maybe it's a scope problem, are you setting that variable in a different function? It needs to be a global variable so you can use it in `tc_reload()`.

Comment: Use the browsers js debugger. Set a breakpoint on the ajax call and see what `id` is set to when you try and use it!

Comment: I tried with console.log and it sends the parameter value. @RiggsFolly

Comment: So `console.log(id)` shows the value, but `alert(id)` doesn't? That makes no sense.

Comment: @Barmar `alert(id)` shows the id as well, I just get the undefined index on the php page.

Comment: @Samuel Earlier you commented "It's not set". I thought you were talking about the alert that Cosmin asked you to try.

Comment: @Barmar Later I said I set the id to the following code `var id = $.urlParam('id');` and now it's global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.

Apparently the config.php file was adding `?p=login` after the id parameter.
`url: '/core/views/task_comments.php?id='+id+'&p=login'` fixed the problem, it now works like it should.